# Angularjs - Can't call the value from form to graph

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chart.js

My html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <header>
    <h1>Test App</h1>
  </header>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
      Search Names: <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="datas in collection | filter:search track by $index">{{datas}}</li>
    </ol>
            <form ng-submit="addName()">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="names" placeholder="Enter name" required>
                  <input type="text" ng-model="number" placeholder="Enter number for chart" required>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        <div style="width:20%;">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My javascript file:

```
var myApp =angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {
          $scope.collection = [];
          $scope.addName = function () {
            $scope.collection.push($scope.names);
            $scope.names = '';
            $scope.number = this.number;
          };

          var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, $scope.number],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I am new to angular and javascript. I am trying to get user value from form amd would like to use in data in the dataset so that my graph value would be according to the user input.

Please help where I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use like that because data is an array in your chart,

You can do something like this,

```
$scope.newData = data.data;
$scope.newData.push($scope.number);
```

And assign the values in graph

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/mvdwgzt9/1/)**

Anyway what i would recommend is there are lot of chart libraries available to support angularjs such as HighCharts-ng and nvd3. Try to use one of them.

Comment: I am sorry but i dont know how to use it exactly...could you please correct and send me the complete code?? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ShahidShabbir check the Demo, mark as answer if it has helped

Comment: when I enter the number in form, it doesnt show on line graph :(